# Audio and Video File arent playing in sync

Tags: reactjs, audio, video, synchronization, timing

I'm creating a Karaoke WebApp in React for some friends of mine and me.

In my Karaoke App, i'm using multiple Media Files, at least two per song:

- One MP4 File which contains the video and the instrumental of the song as audio track
- One MP3 File with the original vocals of the song, which can be played at a low volume to help the Karaoke singers to keep the correct Rhytm and Pacing

My problem is that the Video file and the MP3 File often are out of sync. I added this function, but it does not work as expected. Sometimes the media files stay out of sync.

Code for Syncing the media files:

```
    playerVideo.pause();
    playerVocals.pause();
    playerVocals.currentTime = playerVideo.currentTime;
    playerVideo.play();
    playerVocals.play();
```

i also tested out this code which removes the decimals (not sure why, but i wanted to try without a bunch of decimals):

```
    playerVideo.pause();
    playerVocals.pause();
    let currentSyncTime = Math.trunc(playerVideo.currentTime);
    playerVideo.currentTime = currentSyncTime;
    playerVocals.currentTime = currentSyncTime;
    playerVideo.play();
    playerVocals.play();
```

I can't figure out why, but the Video and Audio still are often out of sync.. Any ideas on what causes this and how to fix this? I want both Media Files to always be in sync, there is no other usecase than both these files always being at the same position.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll get a faster Answer if you provide example media files. It's not a copyright issue if done for educational purposes (links in comments can be removed later on). Otherwise with no testable files, the answer to _"Audio and Video File aren't playing in sync"_ is just guessing. Upload online to your web space or maybe your online storage account (_eg:_ a Gmail login also gives you Google Drive storage).

Comment: You need  a more accurate timing., with Web Audio API.  There are many libraries that take care of managing  a  rock-solid multitrack timeline

Comment: VC.One thanks for your answer, but i really feel uncomfortable uploading these things. Maybe it helps to know this: the videos are h264 mp4 files with around 40mb, the vocals audio is mp3 with around 2mb. the files are the exact same lenght and are exported from the same premiere pro project.

@pierpy thanks for your anser, that sounds exactly like what im looking for. i will research some libraries. do you have a recommendation by any chance? thanks in advance!

Comment: No recommendations... Just pick one